# Shortest word not in dynamic set

Tags: data-structures

What is the most efficient data structure for a dynamic set of words over a finite alphabet $\Sigma$ which supports the following operations?

- Add a word.
- Remove a word.
- Determine a shortest word which is not in the set.

Does it help if all words have the same length?

**A real world example:** I was thinking about link shorteners (e.g. https://bitly.com/) and how they search for available short codes.

Comment: It's best that you update the question with all the necessary details. Also include what you have tried so far.

Comment: @cupcakearmy Comments on this site are considered as temporary "Post-It" notes left on a question or answer. That is why we ask you to update the question.

Comment: If the length is fixed, the "shortest" available word makes little sense. And in any case, the "available word" is probably not unique.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Link shorteners don't face this problem. When they generate a word for you, they use a fixed-length words, so it suffices to keep a dictionary of all words that are currently in use.  Also most words are not in use, so for their purpose it suffices for them to pick a random word, check that it is not in use, and if it is, repeat.

If you actually needed to face this problem, probably a reasonable approach is to have a separate dictionary for each length, where the dictionary for length $\ell$ keeps track of the words of length $\ell$.  Each dictionary could be stored, for instance, as a trie (where each node of the trie is augmented with the number of leafs found underneath that node); then it is easy to find a word that is not in the dictionary in $O(\ell)$ time.  You can also keep track of all lengths that are missing at least one word, in a self-balancing binary tree, which makes it easy to find in logarithmic time the length of a shortest word that is not in the set (I recommend you maintain a pointer from each dictionary to its corresponding leaf in this tree, and vice versa).  Putting all of this together, all operations can be implemented in $O(\ell)$ time, plus a term that is logarithmic in the total number of different lengths.

Comment: @KellyBundy, oops.  Thank you, you have spotted a problem in my answer.  See updated answer for perhaps a better solution.